# How to add one month to a date here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date variables. The first one defaults to last friday. Based on this date I'm trying to add a month to it. When I try the following code, it does not seem to work.

```
var StartDate = new Date()
var DayOfWeek = 5;//friday

StartDate.setDate(StartDate.getDate() + (dayOfWeek - 7 - StartDate.getDay()) % 7);
```

This does not seem to work.

```
var EndDate = new Date(StartDate)
EndDate.setDate(EndDate.getMonth() + 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is you have to set the month not the date.

Change your end date code to be:

```
var EndDate = new Date(StarteDate);
var x = 1;

EndDate.setMonth(EndDate.getMonth() + x);
```

Here's a reference on setMonth http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp

Comment: Nice answer! But why is the 0 neccassary? Seems to work without: http://jsfiddle.net/kd37bnuf/1/ , or what do you mean?

Comment: Yea it does work so I edited back to the way I had it.

Comment: I thougt... +1 for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a month by doing this:

In general:

```
var b = new Date();

var a = new Date(new Date().setMonth(b.getMonth()+1)); //<< this line

alert(a);
```

Your code:

```
var StartDate = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = 5;
StartDate.setDate(StartDate.getDate() + (dayOfWeek + 7 - StartDate.getDay()) % 7);
var EndDate = new Date(StartDate)
EndDate.setMonth(EndDate.getMonth() + 1);
alert(EndDate); //remove...
```

[JS Fiddle DEMO with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/kd37bnuf/)